# Prevent JavaScript from losing not existing Element references

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, events, onload

I am call a function right at the beginning of my document, which has an array of elements, that don't exists yet (because the page hasn't loaded) like so:

```
myElements([document.body, document.getElementById('foo'), document.getElementById('bar')]);
```

Then I have a function that adds all elements of the array to another array for later use (to make thing easier I'm going to use global variables in this example):

```
function myElements(elements){

window.list = elements;

}
```

The problem I'm having, is that window.list is empty, because the elements don't exist in the DOM yet. JavaScript returns null for each one. I can't wrap the functions in window.onload either, because I need them **before** the page has loaded.
Is there a way to save non-existing element references other then by ID, class, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you just want to save an array of ids and classes for later use? e.g. `var ref = ['#foo', '.bar', '#one', '.two']`

Comment: Wait - you need references to elements that are not yet loaded? I feel like that's impossible.

Comment: No. I **don't** want to use classes and ids. I want to save the direct element reference. The problem is however, that there seems to be no way to do so before the window has loaded.

Comment: @linstantnoodles Exactly. I hope not...

Comment: Put the script just before `</body>` then.

Comment: The problem with that is, is that I am not the only one using the script and it has to be as easy as possible.

Comment: Can you provide more information on why you need to do this? What are the other constraints? There might be a better / different approach.

Comment: The reason why I need this, is because I want to modify the elements separately, when the page loads (attach event listener, etc). When the page loads I am referencing the variable window.list (in the example).

Answer (score 0):

If you put your script just before `</body>` you have access to the elements before the onLoad event is fired, i.e.:

```
... all your other html here ...

<script>
...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, wait for the the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: Unfortunately this will also cause trouble with the other functions in the script.

Comment: That's not obvious from your question at all and without knowing *how* it causes trouble I can't help you further I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. I'm going to rephrase the question and repost it.